# Azure Rest API: PutBlockList - Commit uncommitted blocks to a different blob?

Tags: api, rest, azure

I'm trying to do some automation by using the Azure Rest API (using win 8 app) to try to read a blob being written to by another worker role. This other logging worker role is "PUT"ting all these blocks to a blob, and then at the top of the hour commits all these blocks, compresses them then starts a new one. I don't own this logger and would like to try to do this around it without bothering anything.

Here is what I'm doing:

1. Get the list of all uncommitted blocks from that blob file
2. Commit that list to that blob and then read/transform as I need

My current approach works for me but it causes issues with the logger, possibly crashing an instance, and definitely losing data when it commits its blob.  To prevent this, I've been trying and failing to commit these uncommitted blocks to another temp blob and then reading it from there.

It always returns with a 400:  Invalid Block list, when I call PutBlockList.  The same exact call succeeds when using the blob file that I got the uncommitted blocks from.  It also succeeds to the temp blob if the list of uncommitted blocks is empty.
I've tried to copy the blob, but it fails with a 404: BlobNotFound since it has no content until the blob is committed.
I've tried snapshots, but the documentation states that it omits uncommitted blocks.  There is also no documentation of getting the actual data of the uncommitted blocks instead of just the blockids.

So is it possible to commit a blob's uncommitted blocks to a different blob?